# Should I have a Rails migration outside of the migrations folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I'm doing a big change to a project, changing the data structure by having a `Company` model absorb its has_one `SupplierTerms` model. All the fields will go into the `Company` and the `SupplierTerms` will be deleted.

Because I need to shift data as well as the structure, here is the order of operations:

1. Create the new fields.
2. Copy the data over to the new fields.
3. Delete the old fields.

A co-worker suggested I make a rake task for each separate operation. In other words, not having this as part of the `db/migrations/` system.

**What's the best way to do this?**

If it's separate, I can manually do each task, which is nice for the scary production change.

If the migrations are in the migration system, other devs can simply call `rake db:migrate` to get their schema in the right setup.

Comment: I think you should keep the migrations in the migrations folder. You can move step 2 into a rake task and run it in the background. Also keep the last step till you're absolutely sure that the migration is complete.

Answer (score 0):

#### Keep the migrations in the migration folder

The whole system will be messed up if you run migrations but not have them in the migrations folder.

However, you can make a rake task to:

1. Run the "Add new fields" migration
2. Transfer the data to the new fields
3. Run the "Remove old fields" migration

This task will shift the data, and other developers without data to transfer can simply run all migrations and end up with the correct database setup.